# How can I get my application to update the connection string when the DNS changes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dns

I have several connection strings in a C# application pointing to `db.mydatabase.com` and when a catastrophic event occurs the DNS changes IP address to a backup database server.

It seems that my project does not notice the DNS change, as it must be caching the IP address. If I stop and start the application it immediately works, and if I ping the DNS I can see it has changed IP even though the application is hitting the old database.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: this may help... not seen an answer yet, so haven't dupe voted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069022/do-connection-string-dns-lookups-get-cached

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to incorporate a restart of your application into the "disaster recovery" procedure?

Comment: It has to restart when the DNS has updated though, which may occur ~2-5 minutes after the recovery incident occurs. If it restarts at the beginning it would still grab the old cache. If I can't find a nice way I will build a job using Quartz or a windows service or something that pings the DNS and restarts the application if it changes, but it's not the nicest solution.

Comment: Do not use the IP address.  Use the PC name instead of the IP address.   When DHCP is enabled the IP addresses expire after a period of time and the IP will change but the computer name will remain the same.  I don't think it is due to the catastrophic event.  Usually using DCHP the IP address will change every 4 weeks.  the time is an option and will very depending on the settings in your network.

Comment: I'm not sure you can connect over the internet using DHCP without creating a VPN but it is worth investigating. This is being hosted on Azure if that makes a difference.

Comment: If your app can *know* when it needs to invalidate all pooled connections you could call [`SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Cannot use DHCP with failover pools in azure it seems, as they only provide a hostname.